# requireNativeComponent: "AutoLayoutView" when using flash list in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

i want to use `flashlist`to render items to the screen , acording to the docs the only thing that we need to do is to rename the component and add `estimatedItemSize` attribute to the component , so i did it but i got this weird error .

component code :

```
export const RestaurantsScreen = () => {
  const { isLoading, error, clearError, sendRequest } = useHttpClient();
  const [fetchedRestaurants, setFetchedRestaurants] = useState([]);

...
...
...

      {!isLoading && fetchedRestaurants.length > 0 && (
        <FlashList
          data={fetchedRestaurants}
          renderItem={renderItemComponent}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
          initialNumToRender={3}
          estimatedItemSize={15}
        />
      )}
    </SafeArea>
  );
};
```

and the error is :

```
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "AutoLayoutView" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
    in AutoLayoutView (created by AutoLayoutView)
    in AutoLayoutView (created by ScrollComponent)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by ScrollComponent)
    in ...
```

it works fine with `flatlist` .

Answer (score 11):

The reason for this is that flashlist module has native dependencies (this is why [installation docs](https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/docs/#installation) prompts you to install the native deps with `pod install` in the ios directory).

Whenever you change anything on the "native" side of things you need to rebuild the app via xCode (or with `yarn ios`).

After that you will not see the error anymore

Answer (score 3):

After installing the package follow the instruction below:

- run `npx pod-install` in the root folder of your react-native project
- run `yarn start --reset-cache`
- run `yarn ios`

Your application should run smoothly now.

Happy Coding...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I am using Expo SDK 46,
I install FlashList by command mentioned in https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/docs/#installation

```
npx expo install @shopify/flash-list expo-dev-client
```

After that, I rebuild development build by command

```
eas build -p ios --profile development --local
```

Restart app again, and error gone

```
expo start --dev-client
```

Answer (score 0):

After install the `flashlist` dependency with `pod install` then you need to run the App again from `xcode` open `xcode` and press `command + R` on Mac,
after that your error will resolved.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using expo go, make sure you are using SDK 46 or newer, as you can find in flashlist [documentation](https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/docs/#installation)  that it is support from SDK 46 upwards ,
you can upgrade your expo SDK by run `expo upgrade` in your project.

Answer (score -1):

See this tweet, looks like you need to build a custom dev client: https://twitter.com/Baconbrix/status/1542574116850524162?s=20&t=pbf86KkE8JkhY5ZQ4Z_w_g

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).